# Multiple page application in macOS

Tags: swift, macos, xcode8, nsbutton, nsstoryboard

I am trying to make an application with four buttons on the side (i.e. Home, Create, whatever). On a button click, it would load up some new content - perhaps using a container?

I can't seem to get things to connect on a storyboard though. I guess the question boils down to this - how can I use buttons to either segue to a new page or load new content in a container?

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at NSSplitViewController.
Use one vc to be the side menu and the other as the content.